# GWT: Adding style to child of Horizontal Panel

Tags: css, gwt

I have a HorizontalPanel, that translates to a table (HTML).  I want to add styling to second column (td) of the generated table. Or, the      surrounding Anchor tag ?

How to do it?

```
       <g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="horizontalPanel">
            <b:Image url="images/default.png"/>

            <b:Anchor> </b:Anchor>
        </g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
horizontalPanel.getWidget(1).setStyleName("abc");
```

or in uibinder

```
<b:Anchor addStyleNames="{style.blaBla}"</b:Anchor>
```

or for the parent item

```
horizontalPanel.getWidget(1).getElement().getParentElement().getStyle().set....
```

or

```
horizontalPanel.getWidget(1).getElement().getParentElement().setAttribute("class", "abcd");
```

Comment: I want to add styling on parent of Anchor, that turns out to be a td tag when vanilla HTML is generated.

Comment: In case of an specific widget may use : hPanel.getWidget(hPanel.getWidgetIndex(filter)).getElement().getParentElement().getStyle().setPadding(0, Style.Unit.PX);